# Cannot Tag List Items

Tags: 2010, tags

I'm having a bit of a problem with our SharePoint 2010 installation, users can tag pages using either the "I Like It" or "Tags and Notes" buttons in the ribbon but are unable to do the same for individual list items. Selecting a document or item in a list brings up the documents tab in the ribbon but the "I Like It" or "Tags and Notes" buttons are disabled. Any idea where I should be looking to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

For me it looks like a permission problem. Could you please check and make sure that users have `Use Social Feature` permission.

check this blog
http://mysharepointwork.blogspot.com/2010/11/disablehide-social-tags-notes-for-group.html

good to know blog:
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/anavijai/tags-and-notes-in-sharepoint-2010/

Comment: I currently have it set so that 'All Authenticated Users' have permission to 'Use Social Features' and users can currently tag pages without any problems, they're just unable to tag list items.